# Why is this not giving compile error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *const p = &i;
    foo(&p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}

void foo(int **p)
{
    int j = 11;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d\n", **p);
}
```

`p` is a constant pointer to a variable x and can't point to other variables. But why don't we get error here and the output is `11 11`?

Comment: BTW:  accessing a pointer that points to a (local) object which's lifetime has ended is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Who is stopping you to break your own promise? Nitpick: You should add a function prototype for function `foo`.

Comment: Compiler gives a lot of warnings. Treat warnings as errors. If you don't get warnings, you need to enable more compiler warnings. If your compiler doesn't support that, get a better compiler.

Comment: The lack of a function prototype means the compiler doesn't even know about that promise.

Comment: It is necessary to place a prototype before calling the function. The compiler does not make your "wanting" an error, but it should issue a warning.

Answer (score 8):

This code doesn't violate a constraint, so the only thing you could expect from a compiler is a *warning*, which e.g. `gcc` gives you:

```
constptr.c: In function ‘main’:
constptr.c:6:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘foo’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         foo(&p);
         ^
constptr.c: At top level:
constptr.c:9:10: warning: conflicting types for ‘foo’
     void foo(int **p)
          ^
constptr.c:6:9: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘foo’ was here
         foo(&p);
         ^
```

If you have a close look at these warnings, you see it's about an *implicit declaration*: `foo()` doesn't have a prototype before it is used, this isn't allowed by newer C standards, but compilers still support it for backwards compatibility. In that case, the compiler assumes the prototype is `int foo(int)`. That's the reason for the next warning (*conflicting types for `foo`*).

If you correctly introduce a prototype like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int **p);

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *const p = &i;
    foo(&p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}
void foo(int **p)
{
    int j = 11;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d\n", **p);
}
```

You get the warning one would expect:

```
constptr.c: In function ‘main’:
constptr.c:7:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
         foo(&p);
             ^
constptr.c:2:10: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int * const*’
     void foo(int **p);
          ^
```

So now the compiler warns you about the conversion dropping the `const`. C doesn't force you to write correct code, but you should anyways -- the warning tells you your code is incorrect and might invoke *undefined behavior* (as is the case here).

---

Although not related to your question, your code contains an even nastier case of *undefined behavior*: your last line in `main()` (the `printf()` line) dereferences a pointer that now points to an object of automatic storage duration (aka: the local variable `j`) that has gone out of scope and therefore **doesn't exist any more**!. It's unlikely that your compiler can warn you about **this**, still it's a recipe for desaster. So, always be very careful when writing C code.

---

Adding a very generic piece of advice here: Questions like this are often asked by people used to "modern" programming languages that are *completely defined* (e.g. Java, C#, and a lot more): Your code is either correct (and defined) or wrong and if it is wrong, you get either compilation errors or runtime exceptions. **That's not how C works!** In C, any code that adheres to the C grammar and doesn't violate a language *constraint* can be compiled and a lot of errors just lead to *undefined behavior* (which means anything could happen when executing that code). This means C "trusts" the programmer to do the correct thing -- the advantage is the possibility to create quite efficient native machine language code from a C source file, the downside is you're responsible yourself to make sure your code is actually correct. A best practice to start with is to always enable any warnings your C compiler gives you (a good setting for `gcc` would be e.g. `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) and always fix any warnings that come up.

Comment: @machine_1 yes, I mean the general case. Not every warning is necessarily about *undefined behavior*, but indeed, this one is. I'm editing for clarification ...

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the "modifying something const"-thing, the code as-is should actually compile with errors or warnings as the call of `foo` without having "forward-declared" it lets the compiler assume a different prototype (i.e. `int foo(int)`) than the actual definition then provides (i.e. `int foo(int**)`; this could lead to "conflicting types for `foo`" - warning/error or something similar).

After having fixed this, with the following code, you should at least get a compiler warning (if not, turn on warnings or get a better compiler):

```
void foo3(int **p);


int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *const p = &i;
    foo3(&p);  // passing int * const * to parameter of type int ** discards const qualifiers
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}

void foo3(int **p)
{
    int j = 11;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d\n", **p);
}
```

Thereby you get undefined behaviour because of modifying a constant value (even if the compiler does not give you an "error").

BTW: accessing a pointer that points to a (local) object which's lifetime has ended (as you do with `*p = &j` and the `printf` in main) is undefined behaviour.